# Error about double wide hat

Tags: knitr

[image]

I am doing my homework and some column head looks weird due to error.
What is the problem here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a minimal working example. Nobody can process an image, and nobody will re-type from an image. At least not me on a sunday morning few minutes past six.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE. A small MWE that demonstrates how to add your column headings. Your error is in calling the `kable` function, where you need to add `format='latex',escape=FALSE`.

```
% Compile in RStudio to knit to pdf
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

<<Rcode,results='asis'>>=
library(kableExtra)
L1 <- data.frame("sxy"=2229,"sxx"=10954,"var"=6.8)
colnames(L1) <- c("$sxy$","$sxx$","$\\widehat{var}(\\widehat{b_0})$")
print(kable(L1,format='latex',escape=FALSE,booktabs=T))
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :-) I hope good things will happen to you~♡